# Why is "this" used as the parameter in RelativeLayout constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, constructor, this

While creating a RelativeLayout object we write this code

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

I wanna ask why we pass "**this**" to the constructor?

In the documentation I found that the constructor is :

```
RelativeLayout(Context context)
```

This constructor parameter accepts an parameter of type Context but we passed "**this**" (which I think is the RelativeLayout object that we are creating) which is of type RelativeLayout. So wouldn't there be a mismatch or I am missing something (definitely!)

Hopefully this would also answer another question of mine about how to meaningfully understand the API

Comment: The keyword `this` refers to the Object you are currently in. So the object invoking the constructor of RelativeLayout is a Context Object (possibly extends Context) for more, refer to this doc about inheritance: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Thanks, Got it now!

Comment: Wondeful! :) Glad i helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken, `this` does not refer to RelativeLayout. It refers to the class from whose method it was called (Activity, in your case).

This is from java docs:

> `this`  is a keyword in Java. It can be used inside the Method or constructor of  Class. It(this) works as a reference to the current Object whose Method or constructor is being invoked. The this keyword can be used to refer to any member of the current object from within an instance Method or a constructor.

In your case, `this` is the object that point to the Activity you're currently in. Having in mind that activity **indirectly** extends `Context` (it extends the class that extends another one which extends `Context`), this means that it can be used anywhere where the type `Context` is expected.

Here, implicit upcast is applied, and therefore you can use it like this:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an View Object like the RelativeLayout you need to pass where he will be placed, that parameter will pass the context.

The context must be the activity that you are, so if you invoke that method in an Activity, `this` will work fine, but if you call the method from another type of class, you will need to pass the reference of the current context, is hard to help without know from where are you calling the method, some options who maybe help you:

```
this.getActivity();
this.getBaseContext();
YourActivity.this;
```

If you create in another method in another Class, pass the context on construct

```
someMethod(this);

public static someMethod(Context context){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `new RelativeLayout(this)` you are passing an instance(this) of your activity to RelativeLayout constructor. You were able to do this because your activity is derived from Context ie. Your Activity is a subclass of Context class. An instance of your Activity class is an instance of Context as well and thus can be used to call RelativeLayout constructor